# The [father], [fatherhood] or [dad] of all tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

In case [parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents) is not specific enough, there are currently the following tags:

**1) Female**

[mother](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mother)

**2) Male**

[dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad)

[fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood)

---

Only [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) currently has a tag info:

> Questions about being a father specifically, as opposed to a parent, where the gender of the parent is specifically relevant.

This makes clear that [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) is simply a synonym of [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad).

---

What to do about the situation regarding [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad) and [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood):

1. Declare them *tag synonyms*?
2. Could [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) have a potentially different meaning and so change the tag info instead?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that we need only those three tags:

[parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parents)

[mother](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mother)

[father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father)

This means that [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father) would have to be created and both, [dad](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dad) and [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood), to become its *tag synonyms*.

This would keep it more consistent ([mother](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mother) & [father](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/father)) and less colloquial (even though *dad* is probably widely understood, everyone who learns English surely knows *father*).

I'm not sure if [fatherhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) could have a meaning of its own - judging from the [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatherhood) this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Looks good to me!